# VMware workstation on Ubuntu 16.04 is slow

Tags: 16.04, performance, vmware-workstation

Before that my laptop had Windows 10 and VMware workstation 12 installed and it did run very well.

But when I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and VMware in it, the performance is not good. VMware is lagging and not responding. During that time the system CPU and RAM load is normal.

The computer specs are:

- Intel i5 3320M
- 8GB RAM

How should I configure VMware on Ubuntu 16.04 to run as good as VMware on Windows 10.

Comment: Simple answer- why not use Windows?

Comment: What you can do is checking if you are using pre-allocated harddisks which might perform a bit better for the VM. If you startup VMware once with sudo permissions you can configure how much RAM it is allowed to use in general and how it should use swap or not.  In addition - 4GB RAM for a graphical Linux environment and vmware isn't that much - please keep that in mind. Small facts which wont make it entirely better - but maybe at least a bit.

Comment: Just to have something to compare: i am running 16.04 as well on an i7 with 16GB RAM, VMware workstation 11 and inside VMware running bothh 1xWin8 & 1xArch at the same time. Even with those specs and having messed around a lot - i have lags from time to time. But i had them aswell with 14.04 before - so it sint a 16.04 effect from my point of view.

Comment: Try VirtualBox (Oracle), it worked for me with Phenom X3 and 4GB RAM.

Comment: same here. top-notch 4k rig and all my virtual machines perform very well with no hickups on other distros. on ubuntu its just a pain. you have to restart all every hour to keep working. its so bad that it even freezes ubuntu entirely.